# How to track everything that happens to an object?

Tags: java

I have come across a bug when a value in a collection (`ArrayList`) is replaced by an unknown piece of code (the `ArrayList` instance remains the same) with `null`. After a few events the real value is then set back into the collection at the same index (`0` and the id of the value instance is the same). There are several custom frameworks at play that may have accessed the collection through reflection and I cannot find the culprit.

I have tried debugging with proxies and unmodifiable lists but to no avail. The problem, I think, is that the `ArrayList` instance is created by one of the frameworks that may keep references to the list.

It occurred to me that it would be mighty nice to have a log of everything that happened to the collection and the value. And I don't just mean changes of the state but also becoming referenced from wherever. Is there a way to view a life story of an object?

Comment: what about setting breakpoints in the most relevant parts of the code...?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ yep, done that but still can't pinpoint the moment of substitution or the code that does it.

Comment: then dont let the frameworks to touch the content of the list....

Comment: are frameworks accessing the lists by usual getters arent they???

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ, No, the frameworks are accessing values through reflection and I cannot detach them for test because the code won't run.

Comment: Change the ArrayList to UmodifiableList using java.util.Collections.unmodifiableList() then check where you will get exception

Comment: What are the frameworks you are using?

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki, Eclipse RCP and a number of custom frameworks.

Comment: Can't you use [watchpoints](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fshared%2Fref-togglewp.htm)?

Comment: With custom frameworks that are heavily using reflection to access and modify your Objects I can't help you more. Ask the creators of those frameworks.

Comment: @RobertMugattarov **Are you sure the value change in the collection is caused by the framework?** If such a modification exists within the framework, it should be documented somewhere. I suggest to read the documentation again, so you are sure you don't miss anything. If this modification is not mentioned anywhere, it might be a bug in the framework itself. In that case you should either contact the creators of the framework, or drop the framework altogether.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou, I have tried watchpoints but I can only track the references I know about.

Comment: Also, without any piece of code, it's very hard to know what's actually happening. We don't know how you retrieve a reference to the `ArrayList`, while it's created by a framework; we don't know how the framework affects the values in it.

Comment: @MCEmperor, I am sorry but I cannot post any code.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the most interesting methods of ArrayList, such as add, addAll, remove as follows:

```
public class MyList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {

// constructors

@Override
public boolean add(T value) {
    // log here
    super.add(value);
    // print stack trace, for example
}

// and so on
}
```

It's not clean solution, but it's may be helpful

Comment: That's not going to help me because the `ArrayList` instance is created by one of the frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Change the ArrayList to UnmodifiableList using java.util.Collections.unmodifiableList() then check where you will get exception. Other way is to create an Proxy Object that will proxy every method invocation and log every call.

example of java proxy - you need an Interface to proxy - in this example interface of ArrayList is List.

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class ProxyTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();

        class MyInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler {

            public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
                System.out.println("Invoking method: " + method.getName() +", with params: "+Arrays.asList(args));

                return method.invoke(list, args);
            }
        }

        InvocationHandler handler = new MyInvocationHandler();
        List proxy = (List) Proxy.newProxyInstance(List.class.getClassLoader(), new Class[] { List.class }, handler);


        proxy.add("hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried proxies but I never got any calls to `remove()`, `add()` or `iterator()` - only `isEmpty()`.

Comment: Then maybe whole ArrayList is replaced with another instance? You can set breakPoint on the field that contains the ArrayList, then the breakpoint will stop on every access to that field.

Comment: No, I checked that instance ids remain the same both for the list and the value.

Comment: So there is only one possibility: it is not changed by reflection at all, it is changed in 
"normal" code, probably in a "for loop" in which you get additional pass that you didn't expect.

Comment: What kind of proxy have you tried? extending ArrayList? if so it was not good kind of proxy to solve this issue.

Comment: No, I used the `java.lang.reflect.Proxy`. The list instance is created by one of the frameworks, so I am guessing it might be keeping an unproxied reference that may get passed around.

Comment: If you know where the "original" reference to this ArrayList is held by frameworks, use Reflection to change it to your proxy.